# why would my /opt symlink get removed and created as dir after running dnf update

Tags: linux, dnf, oracle-linux

I am running an Oracle Linux 8.5 server, we have a symlink /opt pointing to another location (/etc/)
but after running: dnf update, the symlink was not there anymore and a directory /opt (empty) was created...?
This broke some apps and had to re-create the symlinks.

Anyone know how/why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/opt` directory is part of the “filesystem” package, and when it got an update, it fixed the directory it owned.

A package can indicate some files are config files, and not replace them, but /opt is not a config file,  it instead a directory, so it will get replaced.

You might fare better if you bind-mounted `/opt` to the location rather than replace it with a symlink.  That way it is still a directory, it just is also a mount point.

For example, if you used to have the symlink `/opt` -> `/foo/bar`, you can replace the symlink with a normal directory, and add a fstab entry that looks like:

```
 /foo/bar       /opt         none      bind      0 0
```

Or an equivalent systemd mount unit.

Comment: great, thanks!, I'll try that before running the dnf update

Comment: would the fstab not be the other way around?
/foo/bar /opt none bind 0 0

Comment: @Sascha you are right!  That’s what I get for doing it from memory. I’ll fix it.

Comment: :-) awesome, the dnf update now doesn't break my apps after setting up the bind mount